# How can I run a code between 9:00 AM to 10:00 AM using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I need to run a code between **9 AM and 10 AM**. The code should not run before 9 AM nor after 10 AM. But the code should stay active between these times. The code will be like changing the background colour of a div element.

How do I implement this in Javascript?

Comment: In which time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have react tag, So I assume that you want to render a div in react. You can use inline background color to set it.

This code return a div that have red color between 9AM and 10AM. Otherwise, It has blue color.

```
render() {
    const hour = new Date().getHours();
    const background = hour >= 9 && hour <= 10 ? 'red' : 'blue'
    return (
        <div style={{backgroundColor: background}}></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helped me for this condition. But what if I want it to be between 9:30 AM to 10:30 AM ?

Comment: `const hour = new Date().getHours();
const minute = new Date().getMinutes();
const background = hour >= 9 && hour <= 10 && minute === 30 ? 'red' : 'blue'`